# Microsoft Word Hide page numbers on non sequential pages

Tags: microsoft-word

Hi I am formatting my document and I am trying to figure out how to hide specific page numbers. For example my pages go:
i,
ii,
iii,
iv,
v,
vi,
vii,
1,
2,
3,
4,
etc....
 and I need to hide the page numbers on pages i, ii, iv, and 3. What is the best way to go about this?

Answer (score 1):

Obviously, there is no way for the system to automatically know which page number you want and which not. I am not aware that Word allows setting such hiding on a page-by-page basis either (after all, pages are *floating* - adding a word on page 3 might move stuff to page 4, etc., and so each change could mess up your whole manual-hiding settings).

The only way I see is making a new 'section' whenever you want to switch from  'page number visible' to 'page number hidden' or back.

That would mean you need to insert a section break between ii and iii, between iii and iv, between iv and v, between 2 and 3, and between 3 and 4; and then change all sections where you want the number hidden to 'no page number' (or simpler, change their page number to the background color, so it is white-on-white - easier to undo later)

Answer (score 0):

No need to add extra section breaks for those specific pages.

Instead, you can use nested IF fields to check if the current page is i, ii or iv and display nothing if it does, otherwise show the page number.  Similarly, for the section with 1, 2, 3 page numbering use another IF field to check if page number is 3, if it is then display nothing otherwise show page number.

For the i, ii, .. .section (to hide i, ii and iv):

```
{ IF { PAGE } = 1 "" { IF { PAGE } = 2 "" { IF { PAGE } = 4 "" { PAGE \* roman }}}}
```

For the 1, 2, 3, 4 ... section (to hide 3):

```
{ IF { PAGE } = 3 "" { PAGE } }
```

Just modify the tests to reflect the page numbers you want to hide